# How do I switch user in Linux using ruby and net/ssh?

Tags: ruby, linux, net-ssh

Using below function I can connect to my Linux machine.
But few commands need root permission to execute and direct root login is disabled. Also, the user cannot sudo.

```
require 'net/ssh'
def sshutm(host,un,pwd,cmd)
  Net::SSH.start( host, un, :password => pwd ) do|ssh|
    result = ssh.exec!(cmd)
    return result
  end
end
```

I tried this but it dint work.

```
def sshutm(host,un,pwd,cmd)
  Net::SSH.start( host, un, :password => pwd ) do|ssh|
    ssh.exec!("su")
    ssh.exec!("passowrd")
    result = ssh.exec!(cmd)
    return result
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882776/ruby-net-ssh-calling-bash-script-with-interactive-prompts) question. It might help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby ssh: interactive command "su": How further after successfull logged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061648/ruby-ssh-interactive-command-su-how-further-after-successfull-logged-in)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your user a sudo user (e.g. http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/306766:linux-101-introduction-to-sudo), and execute the given command with sudo (e.g. `sudo ls /root`). Details vary on the used distribution.

Comment: It was a sudo user before. But now due to security reasons it has been removed from sudoers list.